# Prometheus alert configurations not working as expected

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am unable to create Prometheus alerts based on evaluating an expression, and the problem I have is as below.

The following expression works, and alerts if the count is more than 100, and evaluates the expression to the `query_result_employees_count` say 110

`query_result_employees_count > 100`

But I would like to do this check, based on the `query_result_total_registered` as below:

`query_result_employees_count > query_result_total_registered`

This always gives me an empty result, although `query_result_total_registered` is 100 or lesser.

How do I get this expression to work, so that the alerts will be triggered based on both the counts?

Answer (score 1):

If the "query_result_employees_count" and "query_result_total_registered" queries have different labels, the comparison will return an empty list.

Try to use the aggregation operators (ex: sum, avg, etc) with the "by" or "without" clause to include or exclude labels.

See more info about comparison binary operators in Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators), and about aggregation operators [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators).